# Magento template placement

Tags: magento

I am developing a magento module that should inject some javascript at `before_body_end`. What I don't understand is where I should place my template file. In all tutorials, people suggest that they should be placed in `app/design/frontend/default/default/{ModuleName}/{TemplateName}`

First of all I can't get this to work. I get the error: `Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/...`

Furthermore, if I understand correctly, this would put the template in the default theme. But what if the end user uses another theme?

What does work, is placing the template file in `app/design/frontend/base/default/{ModuleName}/{TemplateName}`. However, I am not really sure if this is the way to go.

Can someone please tell me what the right course of action is here?

P.s. I need to modify the js based on conditionals. That's why I am not using `addJs` to inject the js.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes` and check you fallback settings. You probably don't have "default" there.

First, Magento will look for the template, which is in the folder set in the `"Templates"` field in `"Current package name"` package , then if it doesn't exist, it will look for the template, which is set in `"Default"` field in `"Current package name"` package, and then it will look in the `base/default` folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, is placing the templates in the default theme's folder the way to go, seen as the module should be theme independend?

Comment: If you have a custom theme in the "default" field, then you should place the module templates in that theme's folder. Although, usually, you should place them into default/default indeed, and set the default to "default"

Comment: Ok, but I am building this module for others to use and I don't know if they'll be using the default template..